# I18n.l displays wrong month (one month later)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, rails-i18n

I have a strage issue with the I18n.l helper. I've got the following date in a updated_at database field: 2013-04-09 08:17:26

i display this date in my view with `<%= l product.updated_at %>` and get this **the first time** i load the page: `Dienstag, 09. April 2013, 10:17 Uhr`. When i refresh the page it becomes `Dienstag, 09. Mai 2013, 10:17 Uhr`. As you can see the date is now one moth later. It sticks to that until i restart the server. Then once again it displays correctly one time.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: i found something: when i output ```<%=I18n.t("date.month_names")%>``` i get ```[nil, "Januar", "Februar", "März", "April", "Mai", "Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Dezember"]``` but after a page refresh i get ```["Januar", "Februar", "März", "April", "Mai", "Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Dezember"]```

it seems to get overwritten somehow but i can't see where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found it. It was a bug in the Spree version I was using, they were deleting the `nil` key from the `month_names` accidentally: https://github.com/spree/spree/pull/2427